Error azure bicep logic app deploy error "The property 'ConnectionAceStorageEntity.PrincipalId' is immutable"
I am trying to deploy logic app standard Bicep ARM template using Azure Devops pipeline.
The deployment was successful, now I deleted the logic app manually on the portal and I am trying to run the pipeline again, but it fails with the following error
"MessageTemplate":"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:{0}","Parameters":["errorCode: PropertyImmutable. Message: The property 'ConnectionAceStorageEntity.PrincipalId' is immutable."],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Input parameters are invalid.
Message: The property 'ConnectionAceStorageEntity.PrincipalId' is immutable.
In the Bicep the identity of LogicApp is set to SystemAssigned, not sure which other properties are immutable

resource site 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
name: 'logic-${name}'
location: location
kind: 'functionapp,workflowapp'
identity: {
type: 'SystemAssigned'
}


Hard to tell without detailed code, but are you using a connector in the logic app?

Deleting the resources manually after creating it using bicep will delete the resource alone but its dependencies might still exist in the portal which matches with the configuration mentioned in the bicep file which results in causing the error @SNG

Also that would be great if you could add your bicep file in the post :-)

If using connections (specifically managedApiConnections) this is usually related to their Access Policies and you are for example trying to change its name

